# UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown while initializing class

Tags: android, c, native-code

I am trying to encrypt a text file from android application using .so library.
I have created a c program (encprog.c) for it and converted it into (.so) file i.e library using gcc command.

C program to encrypt a text file is as follows:

encprog.c

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<jni.h>

        void encrypt(char *name)
        {
        FILE *fp,*fp1;
        int choi;
        char temp[20]={"Temp.txt"},c;

        fp=fopen(name,"r+");
        if(fp==NULL)
          {
             printf("The file %s can't be open",name);
          }
        fp1=fopen(temp,"w+");
        if(fp1==NULL)
         {
           printf("The file Temp can't be open");
         }
         c=fgetc(fp);
        while(c!=EOF)
         {
         fputc((c+name[0]),fp1);
         c=fgetc(fp);
         }
         fclose(fp);
         fclose(fp1);
        remove(name);
        rename(temp,name);

        }

        void main()
        {
        char name[20]={"hello.txt"};

        JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_soencryptiondemo_EncryptionSoClass_encrypt(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint a, jint b)
        {
           return 1;
        }

        encrypt(name);

        }
```

I have included .so file i.e libencprog.so in my android application in libs/armeabi-v7a folder.

Class that loads .so file is as follows

EncryptionSoClass.java

```
    package com.example.soencryptiondemo;

    public class EncryptionSoClass {
        /* load our native library */
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("libencprog");
        }

        public static native String encrypt(String filename);
    }
```

In my Android.mk file i have written code

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := encprog
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := encprog.c

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am calling encryption function of .so library by writing

```
         EncryptionSoClass.encrypt(Global.file_path + filename);
```

I am getting following error

Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/soencryptiondemo/EncryptionSoClass;

Tell me if i am missing any step..

I have already added native support for c/c++ in eclipse and included android ndk also

Answer (score 0):

Your local_module is "LOCAL_MODULE    := encprog"  , Pls de as below,

```
 public class EncryptionSoClass {
    /* load our native library */
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("encprog");
    }

    public static native String encrypt(String filename);
}
```

Comment: It says No implementation found for native Lcom/example/soencryptiondemo/EncryptionSoClass;.encrypt (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: sorry, after post my ans. i was noticed  some what  unfair thing  that u are did on ndk , pls change "public native int encrypt(String filename);" in java

Comment: in encprog.c file should be,

Comment: Changing to public native int encrypt(String filename); didnt solved problem .. same error as in question :(

Comment: u have problem , i will notice u soon pls wait